# Unit Test Won't Run Tests

Tags: python

I Wrote code to test that the `Circle` class methods `circumference()` and `area()` are returning the correct outputs. When the unit test class is run, it says that it has run 0 tests.

```
class Circle:

def __init__(self, r=1):
     self.radius = r

 def serRadius(self, r):
     self.radius = r

 def getRadius(self):
     return self.radius

 def area(self):
     return 3.14 * self.radius * self.radius

 def circumference(self):
     return 2 * 3.14 * self.radius


import unittest

from Circle import Circle

class TestCircleMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('\nsetUP')
        circle = Circle(self, r=1)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown\n')


    def test_area(self):
        print('Test Area\n')
        assertEqual(circle.area(), 3.14)

    def test_circumference(self):
        print('Test Cirumference\n')
        assertEqual(circle.circumference(), 6.28)



    if __name__ == '__main__':
       unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing `self` in a few places in the tests. Also, `Circle(self, r=1)` should be `Circle(r=1)`. The indentation seemed wrong too, but I'm not sure if that happened when you copy pasted the code. You can double check that too.

This works:

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, r=1): self.radius = r

    def serRadius(self, r): self.radius = r

    def getRadius(self): return self.radius

    def area(self): return 3.14 * self.radius * self.radius

    def circumference(self): return 2 * 3.14 * self.radius

import unittest

class TestCircleMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('\nsetUP')
        self.circle = Circle(r=1)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown\n')


    def test_area(self):
        print('Test Area\n')
        self.assertEqual(self.circle.area(), 3.14)

    def test_circumference(self):
        print('Test Cirumference\n')
        self.assertEqual(self.circle.circumference(), 6.28)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`assertEqual` is basically a class instance method of `unittest.TestCase`. So you have to call them `self.assertEqual`.

The first argument of any instance method is implicit, so no need to pass by yourself as you did when calling the constructor function of `Circle`, `circle = Circle(self, r=1)`. It should be `circle = Circle(r=1)`.

With all these fixes, your code to test should pass all.

## ciricle.py

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, r=1):
        self.radius = r

    def setRadius(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * self.radius * self.radius

    def circumference(self):
        return 2 * 3.14 * self.radius
```

## ciricle_test.py

```
import unittest

from circle import Circle

class TestCircleMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print('\nsetUP')
        self.circle = Circle(1)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown\n')


    def test_area(self):
        print('Test Area\n')
        self.assertEqual(self.circle.area(), 3.14)

    def test_circumference(self):
        print('Test Cirumference\n')
        self.assertEqual(self.circle.circumference(), 6.28)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```